# DefinedTypes file not taken into account when not in the /node_modules/@types/* folder

Tags: node.js, typescript

It seems that my typescript compiler is not detecting the DefinedTypes file of the modules when they are in the module (./node_modules//index.d.ts) but detects them in @types folder (./node_modules/@types//index.d.ts).

For example with express-validator, the module comes with its defined type (see: https://github.com/milkeg/testDefinedType/blob/master/node_modules/express-validator/index.d.ts) but when I try to compile using tsc command, I have the following error:

```
app.ts:5:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express-validator'.

5 import * as validator from 'express-validator';
```

My tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./build",
      "allowJs": true,
      "target": "es2018",
      "alwaysStrict": true,
    },
    "include": [
      "./**/*",
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "./node_modules/**/*",
      "./build/**/*"
    ],
}
```

I tried to add "./node_modules/**/*.d.ts" to the include option, but it does not help.

Repo of the example: https://github.com/milkeg/testDefinedType

What should I change to make sure that tsc is taking into account the .d.ts file that are within the module itself (and not only under ./node_modules/@types/*)?

Comment: Would changing the "moduleResolution" to "node" be a good way to fix the issue?

Comment: It seems that adding "module": "commonjs" to the tsconfig.json fixed the issue. I am unclear why.

Comment: You definitely want `moduleResolution` set to `node` if you have modules under `node_modules`.  Setting `"module": "commonjs"` changes the default `moduleResolution` to `node`; see [the compiler options page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./path/to/custom/dtsfolder/"
],
```

to your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I tried but it did not fix the issue: tsconfig.json file: https://gist.github.com/milkeg/7cecf1cb4e91fbbe97f8050555835ee7

Comment: I think you do not have to target to d.ts file directly, but the folder containing it: `"./node_modules/express-validator/"`

Comment: When I try without the .d.ts , i am facing the following error:  "error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'build'." Seems all the folders within the module are checked.